# Computing summary data using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model very simple like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: String,

  contacts : {
    email : { type: String, default: '' },
    phone : { type: String, default: '' },
    website : { type: String, default: '' }
  },

  location : {
    country : { type: String, default: '' },
    state : { type: String, default: '' },
    city : { type: String, default: '' },
    postcode : { type: String, default: '' },
    lat : { type: String, default: '' },
    lng : { type: String, default: '' }
  }
});
```

All I need to do works fine but now I wish to have a sidebar that show a list of Countries and Cities with number of Users in that place, ie:

```
London (134 users)
Liverpool (98 users)
Oxford (14 users)
etc...
```

In Homepage I have the simple query that get all users but how can I get these information dynamically?

It seems like I should have a separate model for locations... but I'm sure there is a way to implement this without create another model... is it right?

I hope you can help.

Comment: Please change your title to something more meaningful.

Comment: I don't know how to title this question tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to provide summary results like this:

```
User.aggregate([
    // Group all docs by country & city and get a count of each combination
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            country: '$location.country', 
            city: '$location.city'
        },
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
], function(err, results) { ... });
```

Comment: Does it replace the `User.find({})`?

Comment: Right, you use `aggregate` instead of `find` for this.